# SQL - Order by DATE asc in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I currently build an Oracle Apex Application, and have to integrate some filters. One of the filters should show the dates, which are selectable in a Checkbox Group Item.

My current code shows the dates in the wrong order, a presentation:

**Code:**

```
select distinct date as r, date as d 
from statistic
order by date asc ;
```

**Results (from top to bottom):**

```
30.06.21
30.06.23
30.09.20
30.09.21
30.09.22
30.09.23
30.09.24
31.03.20
31.03.21
31.03.22
31.03.23
31.03.24
31.12.20
31.12.22
31.12.23
```

**Expected Results:**

```
31.03.20
30.09.20
31.12.20
31.03.21
30.06.21
30.09.21
31.03.22
30.09.22
31.12.22
31.03.23
30.06.23
30.09.23
31.12.23
31.03.24
30.09.24
```

Would love if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: What is the data type of the date column?

Comment: your dates aren't dates, but string representations of dates. So you are sorting by the string values. Try casting them to dates to sort correctly.

Comment: @VvdL Can you tell me how to do that? Also there is an actual string value in there, called "null", which s the sum of all the dates. How can I stop that from appearing?

Comment: something like this: `TO_DATE(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')`. You can filter out the null stringvalue by using a where statement: `WHERE date <> 'null'` or if it's actually NULL with `WHERE date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @VvdL Thanks it works. And no it was not actually "NULL", it was just a string called "NULL".